# http request and get a json for response in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

In a rails project, I want send a http request and get a json in response and save it to database. I send http request like below:

```
  def test_json    
    #url is a address like: http://192.32.10.18:8080/GetJson?serial=4306341
    uri = URI.parse(url)
    response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
  end
```

Now, I want save this json to database and then show to user, How can I do this?

Answer (score 0):

To get the response body you'd use:

```
uri = URI.parse(the_url)
response = Net::HTTP.get_response(uri)
```

At this point `response` is your response (in your case its a string of JSON) which you can do whatever you want with.

Comment: It depends on your DB structure. If you want to store it as-is you can store it in a `text` or `blob` column.